# Split distinct numbers, count occurance and return percents of each

Tags: perl

I would like to split a user input of numbers and split the numbers into a list in perl and return their count and percents sorted by numbers splitted:

For instance users inputs in stdin: 112219992221474774

Num 1 are 4 with 22.22%

Num 2 are 5 with 27.77%

Num 4 are 3 with 16.67%

Num 7 are 3 with 16.67%

Num 9 are 3 with 16.67%

What I have done so far?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub main {

    print ("Enter the numbers: ");
    chomp(my $num = <STDIN>);

    my @Array = split (//, $num);

    my %numbers;
    $numbers{$_}++ for split / /, $Array[0];

    my $total;

    while (my ($k, $v) = each %numbers){
        $total += $v;
        print "Num $k are $v with $v/$total %\n";   
    }

}

main();
```

When I run this I get:

> Num 1 are 1 with 1/1 %

Any clue why is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You split the input string correctly using an empty string `//`, what returns the list of characters in that string; in this case the digits you need. Why then split the first element of `@Array` again, and by space? That results in your `%numbers` being `(1 => 1)`.

As the `split //` returned the list of digits just count them.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

while (1) {
    print "Enter the number: ";

    my $num = <STDIN>;
    chomp $num;
    if ($num =~ /[^0-9]/) {
        say "Non-digit(s) in input $num. Please try again.";
        next;
    }

    my @digits = split //, $num;   #/

    my %freq;
    ++$freq{$_} for @digits;

    for (sort keys %freq) { 
        say "Num are $freq{$_} with ", (sprintf "%.2f%%", ($freq{$_}/@digits)*100) 
    }
}
```

Quit with Ctrl-C.  With input of `112219992221474774` the output is

```
Num 1 are 4 with 22.22%
Num 2 are 5 with 27.78%
Num 4 are 3 with 16.67%
Num 7 are 3 with 16.67%
Num 9 are 3 with 16.67%
```

Comment: what about the count of each number?

Comment: Like this:
Num 1 are 4 with 22.22%
Num 2 are 5 with 27.78%
Num 4 are 3 with 16.67%
Num 7 are 3 with 16.67%
Num 9 are 3 with 16.67%

Comment: The count is $freq{$_} so you just add that to your string. The reason the percentatge wasn't working as you did it is because you can only interpolate variables into a string, not the division operator.

Comment: @feijao Added that and edited explanation. Let me know if it's not clear

Comment: I get an error like:
Enter the number: 112219992221474774
Can't locate object method "freq" via package "1" (perhaps you forgot to load "1"?) at /Volumes/Downloads/Text-5.pl line 18, <STDIN> line 1.

Comment: @feijao oh, I lost the `$` in front in pasting .. fixed